# How to detect certain numbers from a dice roller?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dice

I have made a text-based RPG that uses dice rolling for the combat system. If you get a `1`, your attack is forfeited. You can keep rolling until you get a one, or type `'attack'`. I made a dice roller, and I just want to know, how to make it detect if the roll is `2` through `6`. Here is the code:

```
print ("Type roll to roll the dice")
rollKeeper = ("1")
while rollKeeper == ("1"):
    rollOn = input ( )
    if rollOn == ("roll"):
        import random
        def rollDice():
            damage = random.randint(1,6)
        damage = random.randint (1,6)
        print (damage)
```

So I want to get it do detect numbers `2` through `6`, and that's it. I know about

```
if damage == ("1"):
```

but that is already part of my game. I just need to be able to detect if it is any of the others (up to `6`).

Comment: uh, `if (damage >=2) || (damage <= 6)`?

Comment: *"detect numbers 2 through 6"* - `if damage in range(2, 7)`?

Comment: @MarcB you mean logical or: `or`, not bitwise or: `||`. Python can also chain those signs: `if 2 <= damage <= 6:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roll it into a function, since it's reusable.

```
import random

def roll_die():
    return random.randint(1,6)
```

then just test.

```
result = roll_die()
if result == 1:
    # forfeit attack however you're doing that
else:  # roll between 2-6
    # do whatever your game logic has you doing.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
if 2 <= damage <= 6:
    #insert code here
```